# Any idea to implement a generic controller for a Quadcopter?

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying right now to implement a quadcopter. I wrote the URDF file for defining the flying robot and it moves using odometry's informations pretty well in Rviz.
But here the first problem.

I m using the move_base as a controller to move the quadcopter around but trying to put some goals in the free space (with a predefined height) it is going to move on a planar surface **even if** in the [move_base](http://wiki.ros.org/move_base) one could set the robot as holonomic (free to move on all 6 DOF).

My idea was to define one more frame (/frame_footprint) or "the shadow" of the robot the moves always in the plane and let it controlling by move_base pkg which works pretty good (see the following image):

[image: image description]

With another transformation I would move the last frame (/frame_link) in respect of /base_footprint. Since it can rotate and move on the z axis it will take as input the **height** of the copter.

But now I have the first question:
How can I control the height? Are there some controller in ROS for a 6DOF flying robot?
Any suggestion for a controller?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191751/any-idea-to-implement-a-generic-controller-for-a-quadcopter?/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[hector_quadrotor](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor) provides what you describe ([controller](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_quadrotor/tree/hydro-devel/hector_quadrotor_controller), [URDF model](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_quadrotor_urdf) and more, like complete gazebo simulation including dynamics), so I´d recommend taking a look at that. As demonstrated in the [indoor SLAM demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJbJbcZVY28), most capabilities required for indoor navigation as required by move_base are already available, so it should be relatively easy to create a move_base config. Unfortunately I´m not aware of an existing one.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-03**:
Vielen Dank Stefan!
That's what i wanted!!

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-09-09**:
Hi,
the code is really difficult to understand. There are some guidelines or documents that describe how you developed such a package?
Regards